# Validate a given path and find total number of valid paths in an undirected and unweighted graph

Tags: python, validation, graph, depth-first-search

I have a non-directed and unweighted graph as attached to this post. You can traverse on this graph only once on each edges. No repetitions. Challenge is to write a program that validates path on a given string as valid or invalid path. And also to find number of all valid path from one point to another.

**E.g. for Valid paths:**

- ABCDE
- ABDE
- ABCDBCDBCDE
- ABCDBDE

**E.g. for Invalid paths:**

- ABE
- ABA
- ABCDBCDBCDBCDBCDE

Number of possible paths from A to B: 1
Number of possible paths from A to E: 2501

This is the question I got for a programming interview. I know to validate given string with below python code:

```
# Adjacent Graph vertices with number of paths between those vertices
route_counter_config ={
    ('A', 'B'): 1,
    ('B', 'C'): 3,
    ('B', 'D'): 2,
    ('C', 'D'): 3,
    ('D', 'E'): 1,
}

# Below dict keeps same keys as above dict but updates count while validating
input_route_counter = {}

def reset_input_route_counter():
    """
    Resets counter for all the edges.
    """
    for key in route_counter_config.keys():
        input_route_counter[key] = 0

def valid_route(route):
    reset_input_route_counter()
    for i in range(len(route) - 1):
        # Grab current and next vertice in user input and make sorted tuple of it to match the keys set in dict.
        adjacent_route = tuple(sorted(route[i]+route[i+1])) 
        try:
            input_route_counter[adjacent_route] += 1
        except KeyError:
            # if edge is invalid
            return False
        else:
            # When number of possible path crosses the limit
            if input_route_counter[adjacent_route] > route_counter_config[adjacent_route]:
                return False
    return True

# valid paths
valid_route("ABC")
valid_route("ABCDBCDBCDE")

# invalid paths
valid_route("ABA")
valid_route("AE")
```

But do not know how to find number of paths. Can use DFS for vertices that have maximum of one edge between adjacent vertices. But how to solve for multi-path graphs like this?

***Note:*** Mathematical and computer-graph theories are welcome in answers but I am preferably looking for a python solution. I have cross-checked with cstheory and math stackexhange sites already. However I am not good creating python code from the given algorithms as I am weak in maths. Also I did not find similar graph questions. I only found questions related to single-pathed graphs in those sites.

[image: Undirected graph]

Comment: Did you solved this problem ?